# Change of basis matrix from $\mathbb{R}^3$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, change-of-basis

Let $ f: \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2 $ be a linear application such that:
$$ \mathcal{M}(f; c.b.\mathbb{R}^3; c.b.\mathbb{R}^2) = \left[
 \begin{array}{lll}
  1 & 1 & 0 \\
  0 & 1 & 1
 \end{array}
\right]
$$
and considering the following basis

$ c.b.\mathbb{R}^3 = \{ (1,0,0), (0,1,0), (0,0,1)\} $

$ c.b.\mathbb{R}^2 = \{ (1,0), (0,1)\} $

$ \mathcal{B} = \{ (0,1,0), (1,0,1), (1,0,0)\} $

$ \mathcal{B}' = \{ (1,1), (1,0)\} $

using the change of basis matrix find:

a) $\mathcal{M}(f; \mathcal{B}; c.b.\mathbb{R}^2)$

b) $\mathcal{M}(f; c.b.\mathbb{R}^3; \mathcal{B}')$

c) $\mathcal{M}(f; \mathcal{B}; \mathcal{B}')$

I've already solved item a) by compting each vector in $\mathcal{B}$ with respect to  $c.b.\mathbb{R}^3$ and then multiplied this vector (on the rhs) by the given matrix.
So the solution to a) is the following:

$ (0,1,0) = \alpha_1(1,0,0) + \alpha_2 (0,1,0) + \alpha_3 (0,0,1) \Leftrightarrow \alpha_1 = 0 \land \alpha_2 = 1 \land \alpha_3 = 0$

$ (1,0,1) = \alpha_1(1,0,0) + \alpha_2 (0,1,0) + \alpha_3 (0,0,1) \Leftrightarrow \alpha_1 = 1 \land \alpha_2 = 0 \land \alpha_3 = 1$

$ (1,0,0) = \alpha_1(1,0,0) + \alpha_2 (0,1,0) + \alpha_3 (0,0,1) \Leftrightarrow \alpha_1 = 1 \land \alpha_2 = 0 \land \alpha_3 = 0$

$ \vec{e_1} =
 \left[ \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1
\end{array} \right]
%
\left[ \begin{array}{c}
0  \\
1 \\
0
\end{array} \right] = 
\left[ \begin{array}{c}
1  \\
1
\end{array} \right]
 $

$ \vec{e_2} =
 \left[ \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1
\end{array} \right]
%
\left[ \begin{array}{c}
1  \\
0 \\
1
\end{array} \right] = 
\left[ \begin{array}{c}
1  \\
1
\end{array} \right]
 $

$ \vec{e_3} =
 \left[ \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1
\end{array} \right]
%
\left[ \begin{array}{c}
1  \\
0 \\
0
\end{array} \right] = 
\left[ \begin{array}{c}
1  \\
0
\end{array} \right]
 $

$$ \mathcal{M}(f; \mathcal{B}; c.b.\mathbb{R}^2) = \left[
 \begin{array}{lll}
  1 & 1 & 1 \\
  1 & 1 & 0
 \end{array}
\right]
$$

and I know that the solution for b) is

$$ \mathcal{M}(f; c.b.\mathbb{R}^3; \mathcal{B}') = \left[
 \begin{array}{lll}
  0 & 1 & 1 \\
  1 & 0 & -1
 \end{array}
\right]
$$

and solution for c) is

$$ \mathcal{M}(f; c.b.\mathbb{R}^3; c.b.\mathbb{R}^2) = \left[
 \begin{array}{lll}
  1 & 1 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 1
 \end{array}
\right]
$$
but I don't know how to do them. Any tips?

Comment: Show your work for part a). If you understood what you did, the other parts should not be a problem as they work in exactly the same fashion.

Comment: @johnny10 I've eddited the question showing the work, but I can't seem to figure out how to start for b) and c)

Answer (score 1):

There is a systematic way to do this. For such a problem, what you need is simply following the **definitions**. (It is very instructive to do it at least once to see what is really going on.)

Change the notations to make writing easier.

Let $\alpha=(e_1,e_2,e_3)$ be the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$ and
$\alpha'=(e_1',e_2')$ the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Then the linear map $f$ is such that
$$
f(e_1)=e_1,\quad f(e_2)=e_1'+e_2',\quad f(e_3)=e_2'. 
$$
This corresponds to the matrix on the second line of your post.

To find the matrix in (a), what you want is finding the following coefficients $b_{ij}$ where
$$
f(\beta_1)=b_{11}e_1'+b_{12}e_2'\\
f(\beta_2)=b_{21}e_1'+b_{22}e_2'\\
f(\beta_3)=b_{31}e_1'+b_{32}e_2'
$$

Here $\beta_1,\beta_2,\beta_3$ denote the three vectors of $\mathcal{B}$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

Simple – denote $P$ the change of basis matrix for$\mathbf R^3$, $X$ a column vector in the standard basis, $X'$ its column vector in basis $\mathcal B$, and $Q$ the change of basis matrix for $\mathbf R^2$,  $Y$ a column vector in the standard basis, $Y'$ its column vector in basis $\mathcal B'$.

We know  that $\;Y=QY'=\ M X= M PX'$, whence
$$Y'=(Q^{-1}MP)X'$$
which means th matrix you're seeking for is $Q^{-1}MP$.